# getActivity() и NullPointerException

Tags: android, activity, fragment-transaction

В методе интерфейса, имплементированного Фрагментом B хочу реализовать метод, который при нажатии на элемент списка переключает на Фрагмент А. 
    В Активности MainActivity за переключение фрагментов отвечает метод ShowListOfDirectionsFragment().

```
public void itemClick(int position) {
    if (position == 1) {
        MainActivity currentActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        currentActivity.ShowListOfDirectionsFragment();
    }
}
```

Но выдает NullPointerException для currentActivity....

Код активити

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ShowMenuFragment();

}

public void ShowMenuFragment() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer1);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new MainMenuFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer1, fragment)
                .commit();

    }
}

public void ShowListOfDirectionsFragment() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer1);
        fragment = new ListOfDirectionsFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer1, fragment)
                .commit();


}
```

}

код фрагмента, из которого вызывается другой фрагмент

```
public class MainMenuFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements MainMenuAdapter.Listener {

public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
public MainMenuAdapter menuAdapter;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu_fragment, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.main_menu_fragment);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(), 2));
    }

    OptionElementList optionElementList = new OptionElementList(getActivity());
    List<OptionElement> optionElement = optionElementList.getOptionElement();

    menuAdapter = new MainMenuAdapter(optionElement, this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void itemClick(int position) {
    if (position == 1) {
        MainActivity currentActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        currentActivity.ShowListOfDirectionsFragment();
    }
}


public class OptionElement {
    String title;

    OptionElement(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}

public class OptionElementList {

    private List<OptionElement> mOptionElements;

    private OptionElementList(Context context) {
        mOptionElements = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<OptionElement> getOptionElement() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            mOptionElements.add(new OptionElement("Календарь абитуриента"));
            mOptionElements.add(new OptionElement("Направления подготовки"));
            mOptionElements.add(new OptionElement("Правила приема"));
            mOptionElements.add(new OptionElement("Расписание экзаменов"));
            mOptionElements.add(new OptionElement("Результаты экзаменов"));
            mOptionElements.add(new OptionElement("Список поступивших"));

        }

        return mOptionElements;
    }

}
```

}

Адаптер

```
public class MainMenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainMenuAdapter.MainMenuHolder> {

interface Listener {
     void itemClick(int position);
}
Listener listener;  
List<MainMenuFragment.OptionElement> mOptionElement;

public MainMenuAdapter(List<MainMenuFragment.OptionElement> optionElements, Listener listener) {
    this.listener=listener; 
    mOptionElement = optionElements;
}


public class MainMenuHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView TitleOfMenuPoint;
    MainMenuFragment.OptionElement mOptionElement;

    public MainMenuHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        TitleOfMenuPoint = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_of_main_menu_point);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                listener.itemClick(getLayoutPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}


public MainMenuHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_point, parent, false);

    GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams params = (GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 350;
    params.width = 350;
    params.getSpanSize();

    view.setLayoutParams(params);


    return new MainMenuHolder(view);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(MainMenuHolder menuHolder, int position) {
    menuHolder.TitleOfMenuPoint.setText((mOptionElement.get(position)).getTitle());

    Log.d("Testing", "Checkpoint 1");
}

public int getItemCount() {

    return mOptionElement == null ? 0 : mOptionElement.size();
}
```

}

Лог

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.bignerdranch.android.abiturientsziu.MainActivity.ShowListOfDirectionsFragment()' on a null object reference
                      at com.bignerdranch.android.abiturientsziu.MainMenuFragment.itemClick(MainMenuFragment.java:45)

Comment: Покажите больше кода - где именно вызывается метод `itemClick`. И логи ошибки приведите. Показанный вами код должен работать нормально в описанных вами условиях.

Comment: ок, выложил весь код, кроме разметки

Answer (score 0):

Вы в `MainMenuAdapter` вместо использования отображаемого в данный момент фрагмента в качестве интерфейса создаёте новый экземпляр оного. Он не прикреплён системой к активити, засим она и `null`.

Вам надо передать ваш текущий фрагмент в качестве интерфейса в адаптер и использовать ссылку на него, а не создавать новый экземпляр:

```
public class MainMenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainMenuAdapter.MainMenuHolder> {

    interface Listener {
         void itemClick(int position);
    }

    private Listener listener;

    private List<MainMenuFragment.OptionElement> mOptionElement;

    public MainMenuAdapter(List<MainMenuFragment.OptionElement> optionElements, Listener listener) {
        mOptionElement = optionElements;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    //тут все остальные методы адаптера 

    class MainMenuHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView TitleOfMenuPoint;
        MainMenuFragment.OptionElement mOptionElement;

        public MainMenuHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            TitleOfMenuPoint = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_of_main_menu_point);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.itemClick(getLayoutPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Соответственно, создавая адаптер надо в него передавать интерфейс:

```
menuAdapter = new MainMenuAdapter(optionElement, this);
```

Comment: Понятно - попробую. Все дело было, значит, в "Listener listener = new MainMenuFragment();"

Comment: Да, именно так. Обратите внимание, что я сделал холдер внутренним классом адаптера

Comment: Не, не работает... Ту же ошибку выдает

Comment: @АндрейДмитриев, должно работать. Проверьте что InstantRun отключён. Если отключен или не помогает - обновите вопрос, добавив туда новый код и новые логи ошибки.

Comment: @АндрейДмитриев, вы в `MainMenuHolder` в `onClick` код не поменяли.

Comment: Тк отключение InstantRun не помогло, выложил обновленный код

Comment: @АндрейДмитриев, см. коммент выше.

Comment: Поправил - не помогает...

Comment: @АндрейДмитриев, та же ошибка?.. Если да- других идей у меня нет. Теперь код должен работать.

Comment: @АндрейДмитриев, разве что можно попробовать из `onCreateView` создание и присвоение адаптера перенести в `onViewCreated`

Answer (score 0):

Выкладываю работающий код

```
public class MainMenuFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements MainMenuAdapter.Listener {

public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
public MainMenuAdapter menuAdapter;
MainActivity currentActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu_fragment, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.main_menu_fragment);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(), 2));
    }

    OptionElementList optionElementList = new OptionElementList(getActivity());
    List<OptionElement> optionElement = optionElementList.getOptionElement();

    menuAdapter = new MainMenuAdapter(optionElement, this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

    return v;
}

public interface OnFragmentDataListener {
    void onFragmentDataListener();
}

public OnFragmentDataListener mListener;

@Override
public void itemClick(int position) {
    if (position == 1) {
        mListener.onFragmentDataListener();
        // currentActivity.ShowListOfDirectionsFragment();
    }
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentDataListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentDataListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragment1DataListener");
    }
}




public class OptionElement {
    String title;

    OptionElement(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}

public class OptionElementList {

    private List<OptionElement> mOptionElements;

    private OptionElementList(Context context) {
        mOptionElements = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<OptionElement> getOptionElement() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            mOptionElements.add(new OptionElement("Календарь абитуриента"));
            mOptionElements.add(new OptionElement("Направления подготовки"));
            mOptionElements.add(new OptionElement("Правила приема"));
            mOptionElements.add(new OptionElement("Расписание экзаменов"));
            mOptionElements.add(new OptionElement("Результаты экзаменов"));
            mOptionElements.add(new OptionElement("Список поступивших"));

        }

        return mOptionElements;
    }

}
```

}

Теперь адаптер

```
public class MainMenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainMenuAdapter.MainMenuHolder> {

interface Listener {
     void itemClick(int position);
}

Listener listener;
List<MainMenuFragment.OptionElement> mOptionElement;

public MainMenuAdapter(List<MainMenuFragment.OptionElement> optionElements, Listener listener) {
    mOptionElement = optionElements;
    this.listener = listener;
}


public class MainMenuHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView TitleOfMenuPoint;
    MainMenuFragment.OptionElement mOptionElement;

    public MainMenuHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        TitleOfMenuPoint = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_of_main_menu_point);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.itemClick(getLayoutPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}


public MainMenuHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_point, parent, false);

    GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams params = (GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 350;
    params.width = 350;
    params.getSpanSize();

    view.setLayoutParams(params);


    return new MainMenuHolder(view);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(MainMenuHolder menuHolder, int position) {
    menuHolder.TitleOfMenuPoint.setText((mOptionElement.get(position)).getTitle());

    Log.d("Testing", "Checkpoint 1");
}

public int getItemCount() {

    return mOptionElement == null ? 0 : mOptionElement.size();
}
```

}

В новом решении я реализовал взаимодействие фрагмента и активити (в части перехода во второй фрагмент) через интерфейс.
Правда, при этом пришлось использовать onAttach - знаю, что его не рекомендуют использовать. Буду признателен, если подскажете, что можно использовать вместо него.
Всем спасибо